# Duplicated TaskExecutorRunner JVMs in container, causing running beyond physical memory limits and yarn kill

Tags: apache-flink

I have some data transmission jobs running bounded streams in Flink. These jobs are submitted to Flink cluster by yarn-session detached mode many times each day. A weird phenomenon occurs everyday: The **random** minority of jobs, around 5% not memory-intensive, fail because the container has been removed due to running beyond physical memory limits.

The jobmanager has printed process-tree when container is removed. It shows that there are two duplicated TaskExecutorRunner JVM processes sharing same parameters, one is the other's parent process.

Flink version: 1.6.2

What's going wrong with my taskmanager's container? Have you ever seen this problem?

jobmanager.log :

```
2020-07-13 08:20:38,353 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                     - Closing TaskExecutor connection container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002 because: Container [pid=126548,containerID=container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.5 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 7.0 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 133231 126644 126548 126548 java 0 360 3703341056 324345 /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Xms1304m -Xmx1304m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=744m -Djob_name=squirrel_mt_netsec.db_conn_ip -Dengine_type=FLINK -Dlog.file=/data1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs/application_1594464964771_78288/container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:./logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskExecutorRunner --configDir . 
    |- 126548 126400 126548 126548 bash 0 3 120193024 352 /bin/bash -c /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Xms1304m -Xmx1304m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=744m  -Djob_name=squirrel_mt_netsec.db_conn_ip -Dengine_type=FLINK -Dlog.file=/data1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs/application_1594464964771_78288/container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:./logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskExecutorRunner --configDir . 1> /data1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs/application_1594464964771_78288/container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002/taskmanager.out 2> /data1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs/application_1594464964771_78288/container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002/taskmanager.err 
    |- 126644 126548 126548 126548 java 3872 777 3703341056 324345 /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Xms1304m -Xmx1304m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=744m -Djob_name=squirrel_mt_netsec.db_conn_ip -Dengine_type=FLINK -Dlog.file=/data1/hadoop/yarn/userlogs/application_1594464964771_78288/container_e17_1594464964771_78288_01_000002/taskmanager.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:./logback.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskExecutorRunner --configDir . 

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
```

Answer (score 0):

After having spent a long time, we eventually figure out this issue:

Our application running on Flink Taskmanager uses some dependency lib code which are aiming to acquire some host information by shell subprocess. In order to create new subprocess, JVM uses C libs for *fork-exec* technique.

When the free memory on server is low or other hardware subtleties, it takes a little long time(3-6s) to fork and exec subprocess. During this procedure, if YARN checks the memory usage of TaskManager twice, it will see that the memory is doubled, causing killing the process and printing the wired process tree.